# Compare two alphanumeric "numbers", ordered arbitrarily

Tags: c#, algorithm, compare

I am having a logical problem with the following algorithm:

> Compare to alphanumeric numbers "letter by letter", in a way that the order of "letters" is, in ascending order:
>
> `0123456789A...Z`
>
> Example results:
>
> - V123 > A789 = true (because V > A)
> - AB123CD > 12DEF56 = true (because A > 1)
> - AB > DE = false (because A < D)
> - A1B2 > A123 = true (because B > 2)
> - X2Y3 > X1Y5 = false (because 3 < 5)
> - AB10 > AA23 = true (because B > A)
> - VA20C > VB10C = false (because A < B)
>
> The order must be editable, so that you might change that A > Z some day, or 9 > B, etc.

My current algorithm works for most of the test cases, but the ones in the example are still giving me trouble - the algorithm reports them as non-matching, when in reality they should match.

```
private static string _customAlphanumericOrder = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static bool Matches(string left_, string right_)
{
    int maxLength = Math.Max(left_.Length, right_.Length);

    left_ = left_.PadRight(maxLength, '0').ToUpperInvariant();
    right_ = right_.PadRight(maxLength, '0').ToUpperInvariant();

    for (int index = 0; index < maxLength; index++) {
        int leftOrderPosition = _customAlphanumericOrder.IndexOf(left_[index]);
        int rightOrderPosition = _customAlphanumericOrder.IndexOf(right_[index]);

        if (leftOrderPosition > rightOrderPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I know my fault lies somewhere in the fact that I abort the algorithm prematurely, but I cannot wrap my head around how I can "carry over" the previous letters result to the next.

How can I get unstuck from this?

Comment: I don't understand the rule. Why is `V123` -> `A789`?

Comment: Because `V > A` according to the order given in the question. Just as `A > 9` or `G > F`.

Comment: Tried to debug an example?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it. As I stated below the code, my logic problem seems to be that I don't "carry" the previous letters result to the next iteration. But I can't come up with a solution to how this might work. I think I just have a mental blockade and the solution is probably quite easy, but I need some input on how to come up with it...

Comment: Man, I have just copied the algorithm and for the given example the algortihm actually works - I mean the `Matches` method returns true. WHat is the expected behavior?

Comment: I thought this is exactly what `String.compare` is doing?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka, could you please describe when the algorithm should return true and when false? I got the point with the order comparison, but if left is bigger than right, should it return true? If they are equal, should it return false? etc. The solution is really simple, but without proper specification we are not able to help you ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5Dstring+natural+order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I would update the algorithm like this (see the added if):

```
private static string _customAlphanumericOrder = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static bool Matches(string left_, string right_)
{
    int maxLength = Math.Max(left_.Length, right_.Length);

    left_ = left_.PadRight(maxLength, '0').ToUpperInvariant();
    right_ = right_.PadRight(maxLength, '0').ToUpperInvariant();

    for (int index = 0; index < maxLength; index++)
    {
        int leftOrderPosition = _customAlphanumericOrder.IndexOf(left_[index]);
        int rightOrderPosition = _customAlphanumericOrder.IndexOf(right_[index]);

        if (leftOrderPosition > rightOrderPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (leftOrderPosition < rightOrderPosition)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In my example the algorithm returns true if left is bigger than right and false if they are equal ore left is smaller than right. **However it would be good to know what is exactly the expected behavior. When the algorithm should return true and when false?**

Comment: I added some more examples. I am having a hard time to explain the requirements in written form, but basically it's just like any number comparison, just that it must follow the given "custom order string" position...

Comment: @FlorianPeschka, thx for the additional examples. I understood the custom ordering, just didn't know if bigger should be true or false or whatever. Anyway, the code I posted works pretty much the way you need. Have you tried it? It is basically the same as yours except for one more `if`.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I somehow had a blockade in my mind. Thinking about it now, after analysing some more, the solution is remarkably trivial. But sometimes, you lose the forest for the trees... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @FlorianPeschka, yeah, I know that feeling :). I like to use the "Cleaning lady principle" in such cases. Explain your problem to anyone - it could be even a cleaning lady. She does not have a clue what are you talking about but saying the problem out loud often helps to find the solution like a charm ;).

Answer (score 1):

You should also `return false;` immediately if `leftOrderPosition < rightOrderPosition`.
Only continue if they are equal.

Comment: I tried that, but then something like `B2 > A3` will return as false, because `B > A` is OK, next iteration `2 > 3` returns false. But in reality seen as a whole, `B2` is greater than `A3` because `B > A` is the "bigger" value (like 91 is greater than 19)

Comment: @FlorianPeschka His answer is exactly what you are expected.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka if you return false when you compare the first character there's not going to be a second iteration to compare the second character. The algorithm stops at the first one and the answer is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In the ASCII table, the digits and letters already appear in the desired order. Use the standard comparison, there is no need for a specialized algorithm.

Comment: Yes, in its current form. But one requirement is that the order can be changed, so that some day `A` is greater than `Z` for whatever reasons.